# Any examples/tutorials on using GData spreadsheets with gdata-objectivec-client?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, gdata-api

I need to update some cells in google doc spreadsheet on iPhone app.

I've downloaded GData source and example projects (not iphone specific) but I can't seem to get it to work. Does anybody know of any good (or any at all ;)) tutorials out there?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file SpreadsheetTableSampleWindowController.m has examples of using tables and records in spreadsheets. The method randomizeSelectedTable shows how to fill cells with randomly-selected strings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [introduction](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction)? Or maybe you could post the error message your getting or the problem your running into.

Comment: Yep, i looked through introduction, it's all about google calendar, google contact, uploading files, progress monitoring, authentication errors and captchas. But nothing about spreadshits.

Comment: Spreadshit example source doesn't give any error, it doesn't seem to work in sense, that it does not do what i want. It only downloads spreadshits. And i need to find a way to work with spreadshits directly on server (read, write, delete and find cells).